# Generate random number that not exists on a table, then use it on a concat function on MySQL

Tags: mysql

The problem is that when I'm inserting data on tbl_tramite, the query doesn't recognize random_number value. It says unknown column 'random_number' in "IN/ALL/ANY" subquery. All of this using MySQL.

This is for a C# Winforms application with MariaDB 10.3, this query inserts on 2 tables but random_number is inserted on tbl_tramite.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT IGNORE tbl_solicitante (cedula, solicitante, telefono, distrito, comunidad, estado)
VALUES(ced, sol, tel, dist, com, 'A');
SELECT LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 4) AS random_number
FROM tbl_tramite
WHERE random_number NOT IN (SELECT id_caso FROM tbl_tramite) LIMIT 1;
SET @caso := CONCAT(ced, random_number);
INSERT INTO tbl_tramite (id_caso, solicitante_cedula, usuario_id_usuario, operacion_id_operacion, inspector, detalle, estado,
fecha_ingreso, fecha_regreso_inspeccion, fecha_aprobacion, fecha_entrega)
VALUES(@caso , ced, func, tra, insp, det, est, fech1, fech2, fech3, fech4);
COMMIT;
```

Tested this fragment only:

SELECT LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 4) AS id_tramite
FROM tbl_tramite
WHERE id_tramite NOT IN (SELECT id_tramite FROM tbl_tramite);

Doesn`t return any record.

I expect random_number to be recognized and then to use it to concatenate it with a unique id so the other insert statement uses it. I'm receiving a message from try-catch on c# that says that random_number column field list doesn't exist.

Comment: Well is `random_number` a column which actually exists in the `tbl_tramite` table?  Note that there is probably a better way to go about what you are trying to do.  Add some sample data here for best results.

Comment: Well I didn't understand any of that

Comment: No, it seems I did not understand well the meaning of random_number. I thought it was like a temporary name for the SELECT to use it. But I was wrong. Then I test a fragment of the query but did not return any record.

Comment: You can't reference a column alias in the WHERE clause when the alias is defined in the select-list of the same query. The reason is that the WHERE clause is evaluated before the select-list, which is counter-intuitive because the select-list comes at the top of the query and the WHERE clause lower down.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using this statement:

SET @valor = **(SELECT NUM FROM(SELECT LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 7) AS NUM) AS SUBQ WHERE NUM NOT IN (SELECT id_caso FROM tbl_tramite) LIMIT 1);**

I'm using HeidiSQL so I don't know if it was this or something else but in order to make it works I had to surround the query with parentheses.